# Mongorestore - too many open files - mac os x

Tags: macos, mongodb

I tried to import dump of a big database to my local instance of mongodb.

Unfortunatelly I found a problem that for one of imported collection, mongo threw exception, that too many files are open.

I went throught the mighty knowledge of the internet using google and I found some solutions with ulimit and launchctl, but they didn't work.

Finally I resolved the problem in the following way:

1. I created /etc/launchd.conf file and added there these lines:

```
    limit maxproc 512 1024
    limit maxfiles 16384 32768
```

2. Next I execute follwing lines in the terminal:

```
    sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=16384
    sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=32768
```

3. Finally I restarted the OS.

The issue doesn't occur anymore, but I have question. If there is some solution to limit the number of opened files from the mongorestore level ? I don't think that increasing a global value for max opened files is a good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a MongoDB-specific command line option to limit the number of files opened by `mongorestore` or `mongod`. Since MongoDB uses memory-mapped files, if you have a large number of data files or connections you may exceed the default O/S limits.

OS X in particular sets a default limit of 256 open files per process, as compared to 1024 or higher on most Linux distributions. See [Resource Limits](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#review-and-set-resource-limits) in the MongoDB manual for more information on resource utilisation and limits.

Increasing the O/S limits is the correct way to fix the issue if you need to have a large number of files open. You should also avoid using the MongoDB [`smallFiles`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.smallFiles) configuration option if you have a large database, as this option increases the number of open files required for a given data set (by reducing the maximum size allowed for each data file).

Comment: Had this problem too, with just too many namespaces to increase the kernel limits to that level just to be able to set ulimit for one command. This looks like a bug to me : mongorestore should probably close files when it's done importing them, which should just remove the problem.

A suggestion on that ticket is to use --numParallelCollection 1 which may work around the issue (default is 4).

Answer (score 18):

I use this alias to startup mongod with different env settings and it solves any problems so far:

`ulimit -n 1024 && mongod`

Comment: This helped me get `mongod --repair` going on macOS 11, where it would fail with 'too many files open' before.

Answer (score 9):

It's much safer to change the limit only on the current shell session. Adding it to your bash profile is also an option if you need to have it on every bash console session.

```
ulimit -S -n 2048
your_whatever_greedy_command...
```

You may modify 2048 with another value.
If your greedy command is starting mongo, it will be:

> ulimit -S -n 2048 && mongod

Answer (score 2):

Indeed `--numParallelCollections=1` fixed this for me on OS-X, without modifying system settings. I was able to do a full DB restore which previously didn't complete.
However it seems to max out the connection pool as I still get

`2017-06-01T16:55:19.386+0800 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Out of file descriptors. Waiting one second before trying to accept more connections.`

when trying to continue. required to restart `mongod`

Comment: This didn't do anything for me. I still get too many open files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try restarting the machine, not the terminal shell, and then

```
ulimit -n 1024
```

I don't have a good explanation for this, but unless I restart the OS, the provided solutions do not work.